# Merge multiple arrays from one array

Tags: php, arrays, function, merge

How to merge multiple arrays from a single array variable ? lets say i have this in **one** array variable

**Those are in one variable ..** 
`$array = array(array(1), array(2));`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

how to end up with this

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the PHP equivalent of javascript `Function#apply` (generate an argument list from an array):

```
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $input);
```

demo: http://3v4l.org/nKfjp

Comment: Hi @Jan I have a similar array which i've tried to merge using your example code. It's a nested array though so i've had a little trouble getting the arrays within the variable to merge. Here is how each array looks http://pastebin.com/rF8HUDS2 would you mind showing me how to implement your code with theses arrays.

Comment: @Anagio since your top-level answers are one-element arrays with only the `result` key, you need to [map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) each element to its only element first. In 5.3+ you can write `$input = array_map(function(x){return x['result']}, $input)`

Answer (score 10):

Since **PHP 5.6** you can use [variadics](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) and **argument unpacking**.

```
$result = array_merge(...$input);
```

It's up to 3x times faster than `call_user_func_array`.

Answer (score 7):

This may work:

```
$array1 = array("item1" => "orange", "item2" => "apple", "item3" => "grape");
$array2 = array("key1" => "peach", "key2" => "apple", "key3" => "plumb");
$array3 = array("val1" => "lemon");

$newArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
}
```

Comment: how is that of any use?

Answer (score 3):

array_merge can do the job

```
$array_meged = array_merge($a, $b);
```

**after the comment**

If fixed indexs you can use:

```
$array_meged = array_merge($a[0], $a[1]);
```

A more generic solution:

```
$array_meged=array();
  foreach($a as $child){
  $array_meged += $child;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$resultArray = array_merge ($array1, $array1);`

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $subarray) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $subarray);
}

// Here it is done
```

Something good to read:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Recursive:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: there is only one array.. $array1 only and it has multiple arrays inside, how to merge them ?

Comment: that almost solves it but its still kinda complicated and annoying to do a loop and stuff, isn't there a single function to do that ?

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php but it might not work exactly like you want it

Comment: I'm not sure what does it do really but their examples has 2 arrays as well, kinda same ? show an example

Comment: @Osa if you really hate loops, you can _apply_ `array_merge` to the array. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array(0=>1);
$arr2 = array(0=>2);

$merged = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is what you need.

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Edit:

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1[0], $arr1[1]);
```

Comment: there is only one array.. $arr1 only and it has multiple arrays inside, how to merge them ?

Comment: what if there are more than two elements in `$arr1`?