# Merging 3 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have 3 arrays as below.

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => 05/01
    [1] => 05/02
)

$array2 =Array
(
    [0] => ED
    [1] => P
)

$array3 =Array
(
    [0] => Mon
    [1] => Tue

)
```

I want to merge these 3 arrays as below `$result_array`. I have written a code as below. But It gave a empty array.

```
$result_array =Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05/01
            [1] => ED
            [2] => Mon
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05/02
            [1] => P
            [2] => Tue
        )
)
```

Code:

```
for($z=0; $z<count($array1); $z++){
    $all_array[$z][] = array_merge($array1[$z],$array2[$z] );
    $all_array2[$z] = array_merge($all_array[$z],$array3[$z] );
}
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Check your 3 arrays. 2nd and 3rd both have same variable name. Please recorrect it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple arrays from one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544985/merge-multiple-arrays-from-one-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply foreach over the first array and use the index as the key to the other arrays.

```
foreach ( $array1 as $idx => $val ) {
    $all_array[] = [ $val, $array2[$idx], $array3[$idx] ];
}
```

> Remember this will only work if all 3 arrays are the same length, you might like to check that first

Comment: That nice way of doing it RiggsFolly.

Answer (score 2):

Create an sample array and push to each array value with respective key

```
$sample = array();
for($z=0; $z<count($array1); $z++){
    $sample[]=array($array1[$z],$array2[$z],$array3[$z]);
}
print_r($sample);
```

Out put is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
               [0] => 05/01 
               [1] => ED 
               [2] => Mon 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
               [0] => 05/02 
               [1] => P 
               [2] => Tue 
        ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply walk through the first array with a foreach loop then access the corresponding arrays and combine the results into one big array. This will only work if the arrays are the same length so it's worth checking that before to stop any errors. Something like this:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['05/01', '05/02'];
$arr2 = ['ED', 'P'];
$arr3 = ['Mon', 'Tue'];

$combined = [];
if (count($arr1) != count($arr2) || count($arr1) != count($arr3))
  die("Array lengths do not match!");

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    $combined[] = [$val, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key]];
}

var_dump($combined);
```

You can see an eval.in of this working here - https://eval.in/833893

Answer (score 2):

this work for n of arrays and dynamic length of array

```
function mergeArrays(...$arrays)
{

    $length = count($arrays[0]);
    $result = [];
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        $temp = [];
        foreach ($arrays as $array)
            $temp[] = $array[$i];

        $result[] = $temp;
    }

    return $result;

}
```

---

```
$x = mergeArrays(['05/01' , '05/02'] , ['ED' , 'P'] , ['Mon' , 'Tus']);
$y = mergeArrays(['05/01' , '05/02' , 'X'] , ['ED' , 'P' , 'Y'] , ['Mon' , 'Tus' , 'Z'] , ['A' , 'B' , 'C']);

var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function merge($file_name, $titles, $description)
 {
    $result = array();
    foreach($file_name as $key=>$name )
    {
      $result[] = array( 'file_name' => $name, 'title' => $titles[$key], 
     'description' => $description[ $key ] );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = Array
(
    '05/01',
    '05/02'
);

    $array2 = Array
(
    'ED',
    'P'
);

$array3 =Array
(
    'Mon',
    'Tue'
);
$result_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val)
{
    $result_array[$key] = array($array1[$key],$array2[$key],$array3[$key]);
}
echo "<PRE>"; print_r($result_array);
```