# php array_merge looping or similar

Tags: php, array-merge

Asking for help here, cannot figure it out myself.
Need to merge a dynamic number of arrays, but dont know how to loop the array_merge.

Right now it looks like this:

```
for($i=0;$<$icount;$i++){
$newContent[$i] = array_merge($content[0][$i], $content[1][$i], $content[2][$i], $content[3][$i]);
};// etc.. the numbers keeps growing.
```

This works, but i have to add arrays manually.

Tryed the answers from the topic of possible duplicate, but nothing gave me the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple arrays from one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544985/merge-multiple-arrays-from-one-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, got it answered on rus stackoverflaw.

[answred](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702361/array-merge-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

```
for($i=0;$<$icount;$i++){
    $newContent[] = call_user_func_array(
        'array_merge',
        array_column($content, $i)
    );
}
```